# How can I share helm chart custom-values.yaml files between multiple charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a situation where I have two charts: `frontend` and `backend` that both depend on `mylib`, a *library* chart.  The library chart has common templates that are used by the `backend` and `frontend` charts.  `backend` and `frontend` each have values.yaml files specific to their charts.

I also need to have a separate values file for each stack that we deploy to (dev, staging, production) which gets merged with the default `values.yaml` file.  I want to share those values files between the frontend and backend charts without maintaining the custom values files in both places.  However each of those charts are built and published to separate Helm Repositories.

I thought that maybe I could place these values files in the library chart and reference them when installing the chart. For example:

`helm install test-service myservice --values values.yaml --values mylib/stack-values/values-dev.yaml`

I have tried all variations of paths to reference the `values-dev.yaml` file in the library chart but all have failed.  I believe there may be limitations on referencing files in the library chart via the `--values` parameter.

Is there a way to achieve my goal of sharing the `values-*.yaml` files between multiple charts without having to build it into each of those charts?

My directory structure looks like this, but the backend and frontend charts are built and published to separate Helm repositories:

```
├── backend
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── charts
│   │   └── mylib-0.4.11.tgz
│   ├── templates
│   └── values.yaml
├── frontend
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── charts
│   │   └── mylib-0.4.11.tgz
│   ├── templates
│   └── values.yaml
├── mylib
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── stack-values
│   │   ├── values-dev.yaml
│   │   └── values-loadtest.yaml
│   └── templates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include other file via `--set-file extraValues`

```
helm install mychart ./mychart --set-file extraValues=./path/to/yourfile.yaml
```

And use the common variables everywhere.